# error installing scikit-learn using macport on OS-X

Tags: python-2.7, osx-mountain-lion, macports, scikit-learn

I'm getting the following error while installing scikit-learn on OS-X

```
MacBook-Pro:~ $ sudo port install py27-scikit-learn
Error: The installed version of Xcode (2.0orlower) is too old to use on the installed OS version. Version 4.5.2 or later is recommended on Mac OS X 10.8.
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port py27-scikit-learn failed
```

Here are the various versions of software on my machine.

**OS**

```
  ~ $ uname -a
    Darwin MacBook-Pro.local 12.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

**Python**

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

**Xcode**

```
  Version:  3.2 (10M2423)
  Location: /Developer
  Applications:
  Xcode:    3.2.5 (1760)
  Interface Builder:    3.2.5 (823)
  Instruments:  2.7 (3017)
  Dashcode: 3.0.2 (333)
  SDKs:
  iOS:
  4.2:  (8C134)
  iOS Simulator:
  3.2:  (7W367a)
  4.0:  (8A400)
  4.1:  (8B117)
  4.2:  (8C134)
  Other:
  10.5: (9L31a)
  10.6: (10M2423)
```

**Port**

```
$ port
MacPorts 2.1.3
Entering interactive mode... ("help" for help, "quit" to quit)
```

Comment: You need a newer Xcode - available in the AppStore and then download the command line tools.